# How can I replace all matches with preg_replace only when not inside quotes?

Tags: preg-replace

can someone help me to solve this problem?

I have this string:

```
$app.url = $cfg.url ? $cfg.url : 'domain.ext'
```

What I need is convert it to this:

```
$app[url] = $cfg[url] ? $cfg[url] : 'domain.ext'
```

What I try:

```
$input = $app.url = $cfg.url ? $cfg.url : 'domain.ext';
        preg_replace('/(\.)(\w+)/', '[$2]', $input);
```

The result of above:

```
$app[url] = $cfg[url] ? $cfg[url] : 'domain[ext]'
```

I also try with:

```
$input = $app.url = $cfg.url ? $cfg.url : 'domain.ext';
            preg_replace('/(!\')(\.)(\w+)/', '[$2]', $input);
```

Result above:

```
$app.url = $cfg.url ? $cfg.url : 'domain.ext'
```

But no satisfactory result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\.(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vlZeH4/1).

In PHP, you can use

```php
preg_replace("/'[^\\\\']*(?:\\\\.[^\\\\']*)*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\.(\w+)/s", '[$1]', $input)
```

**Pattern details**

- `'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'(*SKIP)(*F)` - a single quoted string literal pattern:

  - `'` - a `'` char
  - `[^\\']*` - zero or more chars other than `'` and `\`
  - `(?:\\.[^\\']*)*` - zero or more sequences of any escaped char and then zero or more chars other than `\` and `'`
  - `'` - a `'` char
  - `(*SKIP)(*F)` - fails the match and triggers next match search from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `\.(\w+)` - a dot and then one or more word chars captured into Group 1.